# error de tipo SQLSTATE[HY093] enla funcion bindParam en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

saludo me sale este error

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CotizaEcomerce\modelos\usuarios_modelo.php on line 17
>   bool(false).

Ya he analizado el código y solo se que es en la linea donde esta bind param,  por  espero me echen una mano. este es mi codigo de conexion de bd

```
class Conectar{



public static function conexion(){
    $conexion= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cursophp", "Tec", "123");
    $conexion->exec("SET NAMES utf8");//codigo para utilizar caracteres latinos
    return $conexion;
}
```

}

este es el código donde recibo variables para su consulta en la base de datos, meda error en la funcion bidnParam.

```
require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios{

public function ModeloUsuarioIngresar($tabla,$columna,$valor){
    $stmt=Conectar::conexion()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $columna = :$valor");
    $stmt->bindParam(":".$columna,$valor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetch();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la instrucción SQL:

<s>`SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $columna = :$valor`</s>

Aquí estás usando como marcador el valor mismo que ha de ser usado como criterio, lo cual es un error.

Puedes resolverlo de dos maneras:

1. Cambiándolo por un marcador de nombre:

   ```
   public function ModeloUsuarioIngresar($tabla,$columna,$valor){
       $stmt=Conectar::conexion()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $columna = :valor");
       $stmt->bindParam(":valor",$valor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->execute();
       return $stmt->fetch();
   }
   ```

   Eso es sólo **un marcador** de nombre y nada más, aunque le pongas `:pepito`  la consulta funcionará, porque sólo sirve para indicar que ahí va un dato, y que ese dato es lo que está en `$valor`. De modo que si la variable se llama `$valor` y al marcador le pones `:pepito` funcionará igual, a condición de que pongas `:pepito` en la instrucción SQL: `WHERE $columna = :pepito`  y en el `bindParam(":pepito",$valor...)`. O sea, **el marcador no tiene que llamarse como la variable necesariamente**, aunque por  motivos de claridad es aconsejable que se llamen iguales, **lo que sí es obligatorio es que el marcador tenga el mismo nombre en ambos sitios**.
2. Cambiándolo por un marcador de posición:

   ```
   public function ModeloUsuarioIngresar($tabla,$columna,$valor){
       $stmt=Conectar::conexion()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $columna = ?");
       $stmt->bindParam(1,$valor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->execute();
       return $stmt->fetch();
   }
   ```

Como puedes ver, lo que pongas después de `=` en la consulta no tiene que ver absolutamente nada con el valor en sí... eso es lo que precisamente trata de evitar la consulta preparada, sustituyendo el dato real por un marcador, sea de `:nombre`, sea de posición `?`

Las dos maneras de hacerlo quedan bien explicadas [en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Por último, decir que con PDO puedes pasar los parámetros también en el `execute` como un array asociativo si usas marcador de `:nombre`, o como un array de valores simples si usas un marcador de posición (`?`).

Marcador de nombre:

```
    public function ModeloUsuarioIngresar($tabla,$columna,$valor){
        $stmt=Conectar::conexion()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $columna = :valor");
        $arrParams=array(":valor"=>$valor);
        $stmt->execute( $arrParams );
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
```

Marcador de posición:

```
    public function ModeloUsuarioIngresar($tabla,$columna,$valor){
        $stmt=Conectar::conexion()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $columna = ?");
        $arrParams=array($valor);
        $stmt->execute( $arrParams );
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
```

> #### ALGUNAS NOTAS DE SEGURIDAD
>
> El uso de variables como `$tabla`, `$columna`, que pasan a ser parte
>   de la consulta, podría suponer en algunos casos un riesgo de seguridad
>   aunque se usen consultas preparadas.
>
> Recomiendo dos cosas:
>
> 1. Que apagues las preparaciones emuladas en tu conexión PDO
> 2. Que implementes una lista blanca de tablas / columnas para dar más seguridad al código
>
> El problema es que un usuario mal intencionado podría todavía
>   manipular esas dos variables para colarte una inyección SQL (yo hablé
>   ampliamente de esto en una respuesta aquí sobre el tema de la
>   inyección SQL en PHP).

*That's all!*

Comment: Muchas Gracias sirvió problema resuelto, use la opción uno, gracias.